# Eclipse not picking up when android layout xml has been changed

Tags: android, eclipse

Complete android/eclipse newbie question...

I am writing an app and making a lot of changes in the app's layout xml.  My problem is that when I make these changes, Eclipse doesn't recognise that the project is out of date, so when I click **Run** or **Run > Run As > Android Application** nothing happens.  I have to go **Run > Run Configurations... > Run** in order to run my app.  In contrast, when I edit any of the java code clicking **Run** will launch my app immediately.

Hardly a disaster, but it gets annoying.  Can anyone help?

I'm using the Android Developer Tools build of Eclipse, Build: v21.0.1-543035, Eclipse platform v3.8.0.

Thanks!

Edit: **Project > Build Automatically** is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  By default, eclipse only launches the application when the edit pane shows *.java files, not *.xml files.  So while it was picking up my changes, when I clicked "Run" it didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your eclipse Project - Build Automatically is Selected. Whenever you done with the changes, EClipse will compile it automatically...

Comment: Build Automatically is set, and indeed works when changes are made to java code.  Just not XML.